# Easy and scalable way to track API Throttle limits across entire Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I am interested in coming up with a better way to throttle the API calls I am making to an external vendor.

For example, let's say I am allowed 100 calls per hour. I am creating a utility app for internal use. I have a rake task that makes API calls, my app itself allows users to make api calls, etc. The point is that one account could be making API calls in multiple areas of my app, although I do have access to each of these areas.

So, I can't really say in my rake task "make api call, sleep 60 seconds". What if someone is using the app and has already made 100 api calls that hour?

Is there a way to set up something on a global scale to easily track these calls?

Answer (score 0):

[Rack throttle](https://github.com/datagraph/rack-throttle) tracks the number of calls and provides a couple of options for you to limit access to the application.

If that doesn't suffice, you can always increment counters yourself using a fast key/value store such as Redis. You could maintain two different keys, `DAILY_LIMIT` and `HOURLY_LIMIT`. As long as they are reset every day/hour, it alleviates the need to calculate anything for every request.